# Trouble access django models with celery for background tasks

Tags: django

I'm utilizing Celery within my Django project to execute tasks in the background. However, I've encountered an issue when try to access models using apps "from django.apps import apps". The problem arises when I use this method to access a model, as it raises an "object does not exist" error. Even when I try to resolve it by using relative imports, I still got the same problem.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions . If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has knowledge about integrating Celery with Django .

ps: Im use Supervisor in order to run celery execution process.

here is the celery task

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.apps import apps
from campaigns.api import send_campaign
from campaigns.constants import CampaignStatus
from django.core.mail import mail_managers



@shared_task
def send_campaign_task(campaign_id):
    Campaign = apps.get_model('campaigns', 'Campaign')
    try:
        campaign = Campaign.objects.get(pk=campaign_id)
        if campaign.campaign_status == CampaignStatus.QUEUED:
            send_campaign(campaign)

            mail_managers(
                f'Mailing campaign has been sent',
                'Your campaign "{campaign.email.subject}" is on its way to your subscribers!'
            )
        else:
            logger.warning(
                'Campaign "%s" was placed in a queue     with status "%s".'
                % (campaign_id, campaign.get_campaign_status_display())
            )
    except Campaign.DoesNotExist:

        logger.exception(
            'Campaign "%s" was placed in a queue but it does not exist.' % campaign_id)
```

and this is the log of celery

```
[2023-08-30 16:23:12,258: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Campaign "6" was placed in a queue but it does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boualam/django_email_marketing/campaigns/tasks.py", line 19, in send_campaign_task
    campaign = Campaign.objects.get(pk=campaign_id)
  File "/home/boualam/django_email_marketing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/boualam/django_email_marketing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
campaigns.models.Campaign.DoesNotExist: Campaign matching query does not exist.
[2023-08-30 16:23:12,276: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task campaigns.tasks.send_campaign_task[8444d762-75c0-45d8-bfd9-19920f052752] succeeded in 0.022129367105662823s: None
```

Comment: seems like the id you are passing  (`campaign_id`)has no results try to debug by printing the id and check if i exist in db

Comment: The problem come from celery program in supervisor , celery was run outside django envirement , so I update the command to `command=/bin/bash -c "source pathofproject/venv/bin/activate && pathofproject/venv/bin/celery --app=config  worker  --loglevel=INFO"
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Celery to understand that it's running in a Django environment, you need to initialize Django inside it. I've managed to fix it like this:

```py
# tasks.py
from celery import shared_task

def setup_django():
    """Makes django environment available to tasks"""
    import os

    import django

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproj.settings")
    django.setup()
    from django.conf import settings

    return settings


@shared_task
def my_celery_task(pk: int, name: AnyStr):
    settings = setup_django()  # this line is important
    if not name:
        name = settings.NAME
    myobj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    # ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know is celery is run outside of django env but i didn't think by this way so I just activate the env before run celery , I apperciate your help Bravo !